# How to simulate a group-by in JSTL view layer by keeping track of previous & current values while looping over a List?

Tags: java, jsp, group-by, jstl

First I retrieve the `Note` objects in the service layer:

```
List<Note> notes = this.getNotes();
```

Then I pass `List` of `Notes` to the view layer and set the same initial value for `prevNote` and `currNote` to the first element of the `List`:

```
<c:forEach items="${notes}" var="note" begin="0" end="1" step="1">
    <c:set var="prevNote">${note}</c:set>
    <c:set var="currNote">${note}</c:set>
</c:forEach>
```

Then I iterate over the `List` and set `prevNote` to `currNote` and `currNote` to the current note item (`note`) from the loop:

```
<c:forEach items="${notes}" var="note">

    <c:set var="prevNote">${currNote}</c:set>
    <c:set var="currNote">${note}</c:set>

    prev:<c:out value="${prevNote.userCode}"/>
    curr:<c:out value="${currNote.userCode}"/>

</c:forEach>
```

But when I run this, I get this error message:

```
    Unable to find a value for "note" in object of 
    class "java.lang.String" using operator ".
```

**What I want to do here is check whether `prevNote` and `currNote` contain the same `userCode` value - if they do I want to skip the current element in the `List` and display the next `Note` that has a different `userCode` (sort of simulating a `group-by` operation).**

Any hints on how to do this and why I'm getting this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a value in the **body** of `c:set` will essentially convert it to `String` using `toString()` method of the object. The exception is also hinting that you aren't working on a fullworthy `Note` instance, but on a `String` one.

Use the `value` attribute instead.

```
<c:set var="prevNote" value="${note}" />
<c:set var="currNote" value="${note}" />
```

---

As to your functional requirement:

> What I want to do here is check whether prevNote and currNote contain the same userCode value - if they do I want to skip the current element in the List and display the next Note that has a different userCode (sort of simulating a group-by operation).

Just storing the current note at end of the loop is sufficient. E.g.

```
<c:forEach items="${notes}" var="note">
    <c:if test="${empty prevNote or note.userCode != prevNote.userCode}">
         <c:out value="${note.userCode}" />
    </c:if>
    <c:set var="prevNote" value="${note}" />
</c:forEach>
```