# JSTL if condition to apply on a list

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a list which i am passing to JSTL.

```
<c:forEach items="${actionBean.excessList.newActiveCustomerExcessUIList}"                   var="customerExcess">
 <c:set var="clientName" value="${customerExcess.clientName}"                       scope="page"></c:set>
<c:set var="ultimateParent" value="${customerExcess.ultimateParent}"
                        scope="page"></c:set>
 <c:forEach items="${customerExcess.excessList}" var="excess">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${clientName}"></c:out></td>
    <td><c:out value="${ultimateParent}"></c:out></td>
    <td><c:out value="${excess.excessDa }"></c:out></td>
```

The output page is
[image]

Values in list is

[CustomerExcessUIBean [clientName=Golden Eagle Retail Grp Ltd, cif=1, ultimateParent=HSBC Holdings Plc, excessList=[ExcessUIBean [notifyDaHolder=true, excessId=1, excessDa=DA6, status=New Passive, product=Vostro, measure=Primary, currency=USD, limitAtExcess=5000000, excessAmount=95515540.48, excessDate=02 Oct 2012, maxRiskAmount=95515540.48, openDate=02 Oct 2012, daValueForUser=9, maxRiskDate=02 Oct 2012], ExcessUIBean [notifyDaHolder=true, excessId=7, excessDa=DA6, status=New Passive, product=Vostro, measure=Primary, currency=USD, limitAtExcess=5000000, excessAmount=95515540.48, excessDate=02 Oct 2012, maxRiskAmount=95515540.48, openDate=02 Oct 2012, daValueForUser=9, maxRiskDate=02 Oct 2012], ExcessUIBean [notifyDaHolder=true, excessId=9, excessDa=DA7, status=New Passive, product=Trading, measure=Settlement, currency=MZM, limitAtExcess=0, excessAmount=2586033000, excessDate=02 Oct 2012, maxRiskAmount=2586033000, openDate=05 Apr 2013, daValueForUser=9, maxRiskDate=02 Oct 2012]]], CustomerExcessUIBean [clientName=Citibank Na Karachi Br, cif=4, ultimateParent=HSBC Holdings Plc, excessList=[ExcessUIBean [notifyDaHolder=true, excessId=4, excessDa=-, status=New Passive, product=Vostro, measure=Primary, currency=USD, limitAtExcess=5000000, excessAmount=95515540.48, excessDate=02 Oct 2012, maxRiskAmount=95515540.48, openDate=02 Oct 2012, daValueForUser=9, maxRiskDate=02 Oct 2012]]]]

**The problem is 
When client Name is same as the above one, the field should be displayed empty..as if grouped by client name.**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly (and I apologize if I don't), what you want to do is inside the inner loop (the one looping over `${customerExcess.excessList}`), for the first iteration only you want to print out the customer name.  For other iterations, you want a blank `<td>`.  If that's the case, then you can handle that with a status variable in the loop and an `if` statement as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${customerExcess.excessList}" var="excess" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <c:if test="${stat.first}">
        <c:out value="${clientName}"></c:out>
      </c:if>        
    </td>
    <td><c:out value="${ultimateParent}"></c:out></td>
    <td><c:out value="${excess.excessDa }"></c:out></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put previous element like this

```
<c:set var="clientName" value="${clientName}" />'
```

Then compare previous element with present element.

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897418/how-to-simulate-a-group-by-in-jstl-view-layer-by-keeping-track-of-previous-cur)

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose to create flat object structure in backend e.g. `clientName`, `clientNameDisplay`, `ultimateParent` etc. And populate this beans with data what you need such as unique `clientNameDisplay`. After all, you can display one `ArrayList` instead of nested list.